# How to get Netbeans 11.1 to boot faster?

Tags: performance, netbeans, netbeans-11

I really like **NetBeans** as an **IDE** for my Java projects. However, since switching versions from `8.2` to `11.1`, it takes too long to open. What can i do?, perhaps change some startup options, to avoid doing lots of things that I don't use anyway? One thing I noticed is that it stays on "*loading program modules*" for a while.

I've gone through the plugins and have disabled all the ones I don't use, and I close all projects I am not working on. There might be 4 or 5 plugins active. I'm using `Java 9`. My programs rarely contain more than 2 or 3 classes and don't contain much code. I'm running an ***Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5020U CPU @ 2.20 GHz 2.19 GHz and 6.00 MB RAM***.

Another thing that drives me nuts is that, while I like the auto complete feature, which I can access by hitting `CTRL + space`, sometimes it gives me options that I don't want, but when I keep typing to put in what I want it still automatically inserts their choice, which usually has nothing to do with what I'm doing. So then I have to waste time removing what they inserted.

Any ideas?

Comment: [1] There are two completely unrelated questions here. Please remove the autocomplete section, and create a new question for that. [2] I don't know why NetBeans 11.1 should take longer to open than earlier versions if they are similarly configured. Can you update your question with the relevant portion of the NetBeans log (i.e. Copy from the **View > IDE Log** output). [3] Perhaps try closing all your projects and restarting NetBeans to verify that your projects are not the cause [4] If there is Maven activity (updating the local repository) that can also slow up NetBeans.

Comment: What is the autocomplete section? How do I check the Maven activity? Also, I tried to copy the IDE log but they wouldn't let me post it here because apparently it is too long.

Comment: OK. [1] By "autocomplete section" I meant the final paragraph of your post. That is unrelated to your performance problem and should be raised as a separate question. [2] Can you perhaps post the log to an external web site and link to it? Note that you should restart Netbeans first, so that the log only contains information related to NetBeans starting up. Without the log it's hard to resolve your problem. [3] Did you try starting NetBeans 11.1 with all projects closed? If so, was it still slow?

Comment: I just closed all the projects and restarted NetBeans. It was a little faster now, but it wouldn't respond to anything, i.e. it was frozen, for about a full minute after it started. Here is the link to the IDE log: https://pastebin.com/ggk04G5Q

Comment: OK. I noticed this stack trace in the log: `java.io.IOException: Download failed: snapshots01.mooc.fi:80 failed to respond`. Any idea what this is about?

Comment: It looks like you may be using the [Test My code plugin](https://github.com/testmycode/tmc-netbeans) for NetBeans, and it is unsuccessfully attempting to download something. If that is the case please try temporarily deactivating the plugin: [1] **Tools > Plugins > Installed** [2] Check `Show Details` [3] Locate the TMC plugin and check the `Select` column. [4] Click **Deactivate** [5] Restart NetBeans. Is performance improved? (You can reverse that process to reactivate the plugin if necessary.)

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind for your performance problem: [1] There is a transient download issue with the TMC plugin that is making NetBeans appear to start up slowly. [2] The TMC plugin is not supported under NetBeans 11.1 and/or Java 9. You need to check on that with the author of the plugin, but the article [Setup MOOC OOP Java Development Environment](http://www.javaneversleep.com/How-to-Setup-MOOC-Development-Environment/) recommends using Java 8. So try changing your default platform for NB 11.1 to Java 8 to see if that fixes your performance issue. (Edit file **etc/netbeans.conf**)

Comment: [1] I do not know what that java.io.IOException is about. [2] I use the TMC plugin to have my code checked by TMC when submitting exercises, although I could turn it off when I'm using NetBeans for something else, I suppose. [3] How do I do this? When I try to deactivate any plugin the "deactivate" button is grayed out and I cannot click it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem under Windows 10 (64-bit).

`messages.log` was full of messages like this one:

> WARNING [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: Opening C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\platform\core\name_of_java_archive.jar took
>   XXX ms

Adding the NetBeans executable to my antivirus' exclusion list solved the problem.

Comment: but what if i dont have any AV installed in the computer?
i experiencing the same thing.